# How to write junit test for main method which accepts file as arugment

Tags: java

I have a file say input.txt while has commands:

```
load demo.png 
save test.png
```

my main method handles these lines perfectly and calls the appropriate controller. Now I have to write junit test cases for the main method. 
I have no idea how to approach this.
I tried solution mentioned here- [Testing main method by junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349827/testing-main-method-by-junit) but it did not work.

Comment: Try to implement the logic contained in the main function in another function and test this function.

Comment: Calling the main method with proper parameters is trivial; the difficult here may be in how to check if the result is right or wrong. Would it be easy?

Comment: my main method generates image, so i can manually see whether image is generated correctly or not

Comment: @HarryCoder I will try that